# How to find the type of the file without using extension

Tags: command-line

I ask this question for running an find command.

I want to list all mp3(lets say) using the find command.How to do this without having an extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do it for almost all audio files. Strangely it missed some here because they were of type "application/octet-stream". Maybe they are badly encoded.

`find -type f -exec file --mime-type '{}' \+ | grep "audio/mpeg"`

or without mimetype in the list

`find -type f -exec file --mime-type '{}' \+ | grep "audio/mpeg" | sed 's;:\s*audio/mpeg$;;'`

Comment: I suggest `+` in lieu of `\;` and `\s*` in lieu of the space between `:` and `audio`.

Comment: Great. But I was looking for a more general solution, which would work for other types, like pictures or videos.Can it be extened?

Comment: This command can give a hint of the mime type to use for a given extension, say mp3: `awk '/mp3/ { print $1 }' /etc/mime.types`

Comment: Mad-scientist: every file has a type. `file <file>` is the best way to determine a file's type. Returning a [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type) is only one possibility. Read `man file` for further information.